# Sencha Touch - Get Record on Change Event

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to migrate some work on Ext JS to Sencha Touch.

I implemented some stuff using Ext JS's ***select*** event and I thought of implementing them in Sencha Touch. Since Touch didn't have a ***select*** event, I tried using ***change*** event. But then, I am stuck in a position where I might need ***data*** from the ***record***

It would be great if there is a workaround for this.

Here is some code to make things clear:

```
// Ext JS Code
select : function(combo, record, index){
     Id = record.data.Id;
     Name = record.data.Name;
}

//Touch Code
change: function(combo, value){
     Id = value;
}
```

Here **record.data** is a JSON object. So basically, I want to traverse back to record to find the **Name**. Since the value property has Id, I am good there. Also, I am using Ext JS 3.4 and Touch 1.1 (if that would help).

Comment: what component are you using in sencha touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be something like this.

```
//Touch Code
change: function(combo, value) {
    var rec = combo.store.findRecord('Id', value);
    Id = rec.get('Id'); // or Id = value
    Name = rec.get('Name');
}
```

Comment: Awesomeness! Thanks a lot altrange! I was trying to use findRecord in the most crappiest way possible.. :)